# Widget that advances or returns months

Tags: flutter

What would be the most correct way to play this flutter widget that with each click of the arrow it advances or returns a month ?, I will leave this image as an example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) is what you need. It builds a scrollable list that can be made horizontal and it can take the whole screen. It also works page by page, and you can use a [PageController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html) to control which page is visible in the view